# How to deal with several number in camel case?

Tags: naming-conventions, naming

I have a variable like model_1_5_7 and I need to rename it in camel case. I need it because earlier my models were functions in Python but now I need to make them as classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a letter instead of the underscore, for instance *p* (for point), which would give *model1p5p7*. If the module numbers are dense you could also use a three-dimensional array named *models* and designate the individual models with three indices, for example *models*[1][5][7].